# Changing the on/off colors of a Bootstrap 4 Checkbox Button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble finding the overrides for these css properties. Notice in this example page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/#checkbox-and-radio-buttons, the difference in color between the toggled on and off states is too subtle for my liking. I would like to choose specific colors for either states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you gonna find down is the solution for the default bootstrap overriding but I prefer that you use your own class

```
    .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .show>.btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: green;
    border-color: green;
}

.btn:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
    border-color: red;
}
```

something like

```
.btn .btn-secondary .focus .toggle-on-off {

        background: red;
        border-color: red;
}

.btn .btn-secondary .focus .active toggle-on-off{
        background-color: green;
        border-color: green;
}
```

> > because what exactly boot strap do that they add class `active`

Comment: With some minor changes (.btn-secondary:not instead of .btn:not on that second item) I got it working. Also threw in a couple !important. Thanks.